# How to pass bind volumes as arguments Docker

Tags: python, docker, bind

I am trying to run a Python script in a Docker container. It takes in two arguments, which are paths to folders on my local machine. Here is the command I am running:

```
docker run -v "/Users/vineeth/Series1:./series/Series1" "/Users/vineeth/Series2:./series/Series2" fuse "./series/Series1" "./series/Series2"
```

However, I get the error:

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
```

How can I fix this such that the folders `Series1` and `Series2` on my machine are correctly passed as arguments to the Python script `fuse`?

Thanks, Vineeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra `-v` before the `"/Users/vineeth/Series2:./series/Series2"`. I'm assuming `fuse` is the name of the image, if not you also need that.